# C program that prints whats inside quotation marks.". In a textfile

Tags: c

Hey all I am trying to transfer some data through textfiles in c. I seemed to have been able to transfer most of the data over except for the items in " " quotation marks. An example below of what i'm trying to do is:

```
Example textfile: 

This is a test 123.
There "are (123) tests" &here. // print "are (123) tests" as a string. 
There are a lot of lines.
```

I'm simply trying to print "are (123) tests" as it's own string literal, or on it's own line. Separate from the other alpha/nonalpha chars. I've tried multiple ways of reading my file in using getc, read, gets, buffers, etc. Any ideas would be appreciated thank you.

Edit: I figured out a workable, but messier solution to this using fgetc, thanks to the help of other developers on here. I'm welcome to more ideas.  Functions are below.

```
    int main()
    {
        int ch;
        FILE * fp;
        fp = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    
    }
    
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)
    {
        check_comment(ch);
    
    }
    
    fclose(fp);
    .
    .
    .

    void check_comment(char c)
    {
        int d;
    
        if (c == '"')   // if the character starts with '"', it 'could' be a string
        {
            printf("\n%c", c);  //print '"', it will remove otherwise.
    
            ret_string();   // try to find the end of " string, and return it.
            //fputc(c,fp);  // optional
        }
    }
    
    void ret_string()
    {
        int d, e;
        char buffer[256];   //optional to load into a buffer
        int j = 0;
    
        while ((d = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)  //find " in the file again
        {
            if (d == '"')
            {
                e = fgetc(fp);  // find the ending "
    
                if (!isalpha(e))    // confirm it's the end by looking for a nonalpha after the "
                    printf("%c", d);    //print the ending '"'
                printf("\n%c", e);  // not needed but will next non alpha char after end '"'
                return;
            }
    
            // fputc(d, fp);    //optional
            printf("%c", d);    //print the entire ".." line
        }
    }
```

Comment: 1. Read each lines. 2. Search for `"` via `strchr()`. 3. If found, search for next `"` via `strchr()`. 4. Print string based on the information.

Comment: SO is not a free coding service. We're more than happy to help once you've made an effort to solve the problem yourself and run into difficulties. Once that happens, you can explain the problem you're having, include your code in the form of a [mre], and ask a specific question related to that code, and we'll try to assist.

Comment: The return value of `fgetc` is `int`, not `char`. This is necessary because the return value `EOF` must be distinguishable from any other possible character. Therefore, a `char` cannot represent all possible return values, so an `int` is required. By truncating this return value to `char` before comparing to `EOF`, you are losing data, which can make this comparison not work properly. For this reason, the type of the variable `d` should be `int`, not `char`.

Comment: Actally, what I wrote in my previous comment is not quite correct. The value `EOF` is not a character. It is a special `int` return value that is returned by `fgetc`, to indicate that the function failed (due to end of file or due to an error).

Comment: Please apply consistent indentation. Otherwise, your code is very hard to read. I have fixed the indentation already several times, however every time you update your code, you overwrite my fixes to the indentation. Therefore, it would be best if you fixed them on your end. Personally, I prefer the [Allman identation style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style#Allman_style), however you can pick any style you want, as long as it is consistent.

Comment: I will be looking into how do to proper indents and code organization with my new text editor shortly. But for now I have made it consistent. I am learning oodles of new stuff today. Thanks.

Comment: @CGuy: It was not consistent. :-) Therefore, I have fixed the indentation again and ran it through a code beautifier program (because I was too lazy to do it again manually).

Comment: How and from where are you calling the function `check_comment`? Are you calling it from `main`?

Comment: Something seems wrong with the code you posted in your most recent edit. The closing curly brace of the function `main` appears after only 3 lines of code, and after that, you have a `while` loop which is not inside any function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to print all characters that are in quotation marks in an input file, you could use the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( "inputfile.txt" , "r" );
    assert( fp != NULL );

    int c;

    for (;;) //infinite loop
    {
        //loop for handling characters that **are not** in quotation marks
        while ( ( c = getc( fp ) ) != '\"' )
        {
            if ( c == EOF ) goto finished;
        }

        //loop for handling characters that **are** in quotation marks
        while ( ( c = getc( fp ) ) != '\"' )
        {
            if ( c == EOF ) goto finished;
            putchar( c );
        }
    }

finished:
    fclose( fp );
}
```

If you don't like these nested loops and the `goto` statement to escape them, an alternative would be the following code, which only uses one loop:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main( void )
{
    FILE *fp = fopen( "inputfile.txt" , "r" );
    assert( fp != NULL );
    
    bool is_inside_quotation_marks = false;
    int c;

    while ( ( c = getc( fp ) ) != EOF )
    {
        if ( c == '\"' )
        {
            is_inside_quotation_marks = !is_inside_quotation_marks;
            continue;
        }
        
        if ( is_inside_quotation_marks )
        {
            putchar( c );
        }
    }

    fclose( fp );
}
```

Comment: Thank you Andreas, just from your previous suggestion I got an idea and figured out a workable, but messier version using getc. I will also be using this code, as it has hidden nuggets I've never seen before. Thanks again!

Comment: @CGuy: If this is part of a homework assignment, then I suggest you only take over parts of my program that you actually understand. Otherwise, your teacher may not believe you that you wrote it yourself and you could get into trouble.

Comment: It is not.  It's for my own understanding. I have edited above, my code I am using. I would like to monkey with goto, continue, and bools, so I can further my understanding. Thanks.